# gradle jib cannot authenticate against ghcr in GitHub workflow

Tags: gradle, github-actions, jib

This is somehow strange: I can build and push m ycontainer image with gradle jib to my github container registry (ghcr) locally but not in a github worflow. Even more strange is, that as soon as the git workflow fails, the local jib fails with the same error. To make it work at least locally again, I have to create a new github token.

Steps to reproduce:

1. My build.gradle

   ```
    plugins {
       id 'java'
       id 'idea'
       id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
       id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.3.1'
       id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    }

    java {
      sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
      targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

    configurations {
      published
      compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
      }
    }

    dependencies {
      implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
      annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-    processor'
      testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
      testImplementation('org.assertj:assertj-core')
      testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api')
      testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine')
    }


    tasks.withType(Test) {
      useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    task prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel {
    }

    springBoot {
      buildInfo()
    }

    bootJar {
      enabled = false
    }

    jar {
      enabled = true
    }

    def baseImage = 'ghcr.io/tobias-neubert/eclipse-temurin:17.0.2_8-jre'
    jib {
      from {
        image = baseImage
        auth {
          username = "tobias-neubert"
          password = "${System.getenv("GITHUB_PASSWORD")}"
        }
      }
      to {
        image = 'ghcr.io/tobias-neubert/motd-service'
        auth {
          username = "tobias-neubert"
          password = "${System.getenv("GITHUB_PASSWORD")}"
        }
      }
      container {
        mainClass = 'com.neubert.scaffold.motdservice.MotdServiceApplication'
        ports = ['8080']
      }
    }
   ```
2. Create a new personal access token in github.
3. Execute locally `GITHUB_PASSWORD=<personal-access-token> ./gradlew :motd-service:jib`
4. The image is built and pushed successfully to the ghcr, where I can see it. You execute a local build repeatedly, it will succeed.
5. My github workflow:

   ```
    name: Build and push motd-service

    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - actions

    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

       - name: Set up Java
         uses: actions/setup-java@v2
         with:
           java-version: 17
           distribution: temurin

       - name: Setup Gradle
         uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2

       - name: Make gradlew executable
         run: chmod +x ./gradlew

       - name: Build the motd image
         run: |
           GITHUB_PASSWORD=<personal-access-token> ./gradlew :motd-service:jib
   ```
6. The job fails with:

   ```
    Execution failed for task ':motd-service:jib'.
    > com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure you have permissions for ghcr.io/tobias-neubert/eclipse-temurin and set correct credentials. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-forbidden-or-denied for help
   ```
7. Execute `GITHUB_PASSWORD=<personal-access-token> ./gradlew :motd-service:jib` locally again, and it fails with the same error.

I must miss something important here. Can you tell me what?

Comment: Ok, I know why the local build does not work after the workflow: Github removes the PAT. I can see that in the security log. It seems that Github detects my very insecure way of using it and as a result, removes it. Cool.
Moreover the documentation says that an evnironment variable must not be named with GITHUB as prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: I am using the GITHUB_TOKEN now for accessing the GHCR. I tried that before but I did not realize that

1. you have to set the write permission in your workflow for that token and
2. you give the repository of your workflow permission to write into the desired package and to read the desired base package.

So with this workflow and the write permission in the package settings for my repository it works:

```
name: Build and push motd-service

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - actions

permissions:
  packages: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: 17
          distribution: temurin

      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2

      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Build the motd image
        env:
          GH_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
        run: "./gradlew jib"
```